# Performance drop using PCA with LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I've been following this tutorials on tensorflow on Timeseries forecasting using LSTM:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series?_sm_byp=iVVPDS34q1N5fqcV

My goal was to play around with it before using that kind of architecture for a project.
In the example, there are 10 features in the dataset, but the one I want to work with has around 14000 features.

So following the last section of the tuto on "Multi step model", I tried adding a PCA transformation to get the first 3 principal components (PCs), instead of just randomly selecting 3 features.

My assumptions was, I should get a slight increase in the peformance or nothing, but instead it dropped and the error rate doubled.

[image]

I set seed before running the modified section to compare the results with the tuto.

here is the bit of code I've modified to include PCA:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

features = df.drop(["Date Time"], axis = 1)

features.index = df['Date Time']
dataset = PCA(n_components = 3).fit_transform(features)
data_mean = dataset[:TRAIN_SPLIT].mean(axis=0)
data_std = dataset[:TRAIN_SPLIT].std(axis=0)

dataset = (dataset-data_mean)/data_std
```

Does anybody has an idea as to why such behaviour occurs ? Is there some step I missed ?

PS : I've seen PCA being used on time series before an RNN in papers, so the approcah doesn't invalid theoriticaly.

Thank you,

Comment: you have to apply data scaling before PCA fitting

Comment: @MarcoCerliani : I though Sikitlearn implementation of PCA was taking care of scaling automatically. That's not the case ?

Comment: Absolutely no... Please perform PCA/scaling only on your X_train and then apply transform on X_valid/X_test

Comment: Thank you @MarcoCerliani, I does perfom as expected now and gives susbtantial improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The modified code below works fine, I had to move the scaling before the PCA.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

features = df.drop(["Date Time"], axis = 1)
features.index = df['Date Time']
data_mean = features[:TRAIN_SPLIT].mean(axis=0)
data_std = features[:TRAIN_SPLIT].std(axis=0)

features = (features-data_mean)/data_std

dataset = PCA(n_components = 3).fit_transform(features)
```

Comment: remember to fit scaling and pca only on train and not on all the data ;-)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani : Thank you but I don't understand why. In the tuto scaling is applied both to train and validation data and If I apply PCA only to my training data, how is it going to generelize to new data that has not been transformed ?

Comment: pca.transform() is what you need... because fitting on all is like cheating